# How to Stop Event's While Animation is in process?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-event

I am working on Animating my view where i animate the translation and scaling of View.

**Problem:**

If my animation duration is for 2000 ms (2 Sec) i don't want any user event's to interfere in between animation.

Example if Double Tap on View Trigger's the Scaling Animation and scrolling trigger's Translation Animation.Both animation duration is 2 seconds,But if i double tap and scroll one after another it create's weird result.

So i want to stop event's when animation is going on.

Is there any easy solution without maintaining the state of OnGoing animation and overriding the onTouchEvent to disable events?

Comment: just keep everything disabled when you are animating and enable them again when your animation ends

Comment: @VivekMishra you mean disabling event's of the view based on the state of the animation? 
Is that the only approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that i used:

- Created a `State` of Animation

  ```
   private var isAnimationOnGoing: Boolean = false
  ```
- Setting the `State` in Animation Listener

  ```
  translationAnimation.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
      override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {
      }

      override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
          isAnimationOnGoing = false
      }

      override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
          isAnimationOnGoing = true
      }
  })
  ```
- Use `dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?)` . to prevent event's to be received by the ViewGroup or by children's of ViewGroup

  ```
  override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
      val dispatchTouchEvent = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
      if (isAnimationOnGoing) {
          return false
      }
      return dispatchTouchEvent
    }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Lock UI from events:

```
private void lockUI() {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);   
}
```

Unlock UI:

```
private void unlockUI() {
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to figure out solution from inside the View and Don't really prefer to go to activity/Fragment for each animation.Want to handle this case inside view itself.
As i am in Single activity architecture this logic will complicate the flow.

@Liar